# Is there an IC equivalent of a 3PDT switch?

Tags: analog, switches, integrated-circuit, dpdt

I have two 3 wire RTD temperature sensors being used to measure the temperature of two different liquids. I only have one digital gauge to read the output on. I would like to switch between the two RTD sensor inputs. Due to the way three wire RTD sensors work, from my understanding I cannot share a wire between the two sensors, and then simply switch between the remaining pairs and use a DPDT switch as it works out the resistance by assuming the resistances of all three wires is the same.

*3 wire RTD:*

[image]

I know I could just use a 3PDT switch, but I need the switch to be a certain width, and of a certain style with an LED in the end of the switch. The switch I need is only available in SPST design and looks like so:

[image]

I would therefore like to use the above SPST switch to tell something else - for example an IC, to switch between the two sets of 3 inputs. I could then connect the 3 output terminals of this IC to my digital gauge. I have a ~12v and GND supply nearby as this is going to be used in an automotive application. The ~12v is non regulated and will vary with battery voltage, so anywhere between 11-14v or so.

My questions are as follows:

- Is my assumption the the two sensors cannot share any common wires correct?
- Is using an IC the best method of doing this?
- If so, which IC?
- Does this IC require a regulated 12v input, or can it run off of 11-14v, or have a built in regulator?
- Will this IC allow some power to pass through one or more of the three wires to the sensor itself, as I believe RTD sensors work on this principle? I believe it's only around 0.5v.

Comment: You can get relays in countless configurations.

Comment: We have almost zero information to work with.  Min/max signal voltage range, functions of each of the three pins, signal current / impedance, sensor datasheet, schematic of whatever the three wires go to for operation - ???

Comment: As mentioned in the post, the sensor and signal source is an RTD type. They do not generate any current or voltage, you just measure their resistance which is linear to temperature, with 0 degrees usually being 100 ohms. The schematic of an RTD sensor is included in the post and RTD sensors are generally standardised and widely documented.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the HC 4053 or similar. This is a triple changeover switch. I have used them and found no problems.

Comment: Thank you, this looks to be exactly what I need - after looking at the data sheet here https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/46160/SLS/HC4053.html my understanding is that I would connect the three wires of one sensor to pins 12,2, 5 and the other to pins 13,1,3. I would need to supply power to pin 16 and GND to 8. If I then make pins 9,10,11 high it'll switch between the two. I have a couple of questions - what voltage do I need to apply to make the pin "high"? And it says the maximum input voltage is +14v when referenced to Vee, what does this mean as it's otherwise only 6. Thanks